# Having really weird experience with string concat

Tags: arduino-ide

Having really bad day with concat. I'm not quite sure where i did wrong..
Have a look at my function below.

```
void sim900aSendHttp(String bid, String lati, String longi) {
  Serial.println("BUSID:"+bid+",LAT:"+lati+"LONG:"+longi);
  String httpget = "http://uumresearch.com/bustracking/update_location.php?busid="+bid+"&latitude="+lati+"&longitude="+longi+"";
  //String httpget = "http://uumresearch.com/bustracking/update_location.php?busid=KDF8860&latitude=6.533415&longitude=106.33345";
  Serial.println(httpget);
  serialSIM800.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"" + httpget + "\"");
  delay(3000);
  serialSIM800.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
  delay(8000);
}
```

The problem is with:

```
String httpget = "http://uumresearch.com/bustracking/update_location.php?busid="+bid+"&latitude="+lati+"&longitude="+longi+"";
```

where serial monitor only  shows

```
http://uumresearch.com/bustracking/update_location.php?busid=KDF8860
```

missing "lat" and "longi" variables in the string concat.

Both variable confirmed available to the function as printed by

```
Serial.println("BUSID:"+bid+",LAT:"+lati+"LONG:"+longi);
```

Comment: Which arduino board do you use?

Answer (score 1):

`+` on `const char *` increments the pointer. only String has `+` overloaded as concatenation of the right operand (not left). so `"abc" + str + "efg"` will not work even if `str` is String. What will work is `String("abc") + str + "efg"`, but [small Strings will fragment the heap memory](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings) of the MCU very fast and the sketch will crash.

Print the parts directly to `serialSIM800` or use `snprintf` to build the strings or try CStringBuilder from my StreamLib